# Change element attributes javascript

Tags: javascript, button, attributes

I have a clicker type game in which you can buy upgrades, which cost money. The upgrade buttons are disabled and I want to enable them when you have enough money. I can't figure out how to change the disabled attribute.

Code for reference:

`
+ 1 per click

```
    Cost : $20

    <script>

        const buttonUpgradeElem = document.querySelector('.upGradeA');            

        buttonUpgradeElem.addEventListener("click", () => {

            if (count >= 20) {
                buttonUpgradeElem.disabled = false;
            }

            count = count - 20;
            updateDisplay();

            counterPlusElem.addEventListener("click", () => {
                count = count + 1;
                updateDisplay();
            });
        });



    </script>
</button>`
```

I tried using `if (count >= 20) { Element.disabled = false; }.` I expected it to enable the button once the count was at 20 or above. What happened is that the button never enabled.

Comment: So clicking on disabled `buttonUpgradeElem` should make it enabled? That's what you try to do in the code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Element#getAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) and [Element#setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to get an element's current attributes.

```js
// Disable
element.setAttribute("disabled", "true")

// Enable
element.removeAttribute("disabled")

// Check whether enabled
if (element.getAttribute("disabled")) console.log("Disabled!")
else console.log("Enabled!")
```

Comment: I have tried this code and it does change the disabled attribute to false when the count is => 20, but now that     `disabled="false"`     , the button still acts as if it was disabled.

Comment: @JimmyNotJohn apologies it should've been `removeAttribute` not `setAttribute`, I've updated my response